Scientist travels back in time to murder his wife’s secret lover
I had this short story about a scientist who discovers his wife is cheating and invents a way to travel back in time to kill her lover before they met or something. I believe the scientist ends up the one who is killed, though.

How long ago did you read it? Was it in a magazine or a book?

I'm sure I remember a golden age story along these lines, but I cannot put my finger on it. As I recall it the scientist is a stereotypical nutty professor so detached from reality that on discovering his wife's affair it seems entirely logical to him to get his revenge by building a time machine. I think it's a well known story, and I thought it had been asked here though searching reveals no trace of it.

Aha, David has found the story I was thinking of!

It was in a compilation of science fiction/ horror short stories, I don’t remember the name.

Probably not the story but something to compare to https://genresnaps.com/ray-bradbury-theater-touch-of-petulance-s4e6/

Thanks but that’s not either.  The reason I’m so concerned about it is because there was some kind of clever twist at the where the guy that was going to be murdered was somehow waiting in the past to murder the guy traveling to murder him.

This is "The Men Who Murdered Mohammed" by Alfred Bester which first appeared in the October 1958 issue of The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction.
You can read it at the Internet Archive.
Here is the synopsis from Wikipedia:

When mad scientist Henry Hassel discovers his wife in the midst of
committing adultery, he decides that simple murder would be
intellectually unsatisfying; he therefore builds a time machine with
the intention of killing his wife's grandparents in their youth, so
that she will never have existed. When he returns to the present,
however, nothing has changed. In a desperate attempt to alter history,
Hassel begins killing historical figures of greater and greater
significance (eventually including Mohammed, thus the story's title),
only to learn that the nature of time is very different from what he
had thought.


Thanks but it was something different than this.  The scientist was killed at the end with his own gun.  And he wasn’t trying to kill her grand parents but her secret lover.

That information should be in the question itself, not left to a  late comment on an answer. @Matt

The title says ‘Secret Lover’ I don’t know how that can be confused with grand parents
